# Enabling ssh logs on ubuntu system

Tags: server, bash, ssh, sshd, logs

I want to enable ssh logs on my ubuntu system to monitor actions performed by any ssh connection.
My first question is whether i can see these actions in ssh logs and if so then how can i start ssh logs in my ubuntu system.

I think the log files are enabled from the following file :

```
/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf
```

What command should i put in this to enable ssh logs.
Would be great help

Comment: What do you mean by "actions"? Individual shell commands?

Comment: thank you @xenoid for replying.Actions like file tranfers ,deletions etc. like things we do from WinSCP